# Symmetry of momentum distribution in trapped BEC

Tags: symmetry, potential, bose-einstein-condensate, collective-excitations

Is the momentum distribution of excitations in a BEC symmetric? Even if there is a step potential (which I think should not make a difference because this is in real space)? I think yes, because excitations are 'symmetric' (with a $+k$ you always have a $-k$ excitation, right?).

Comment: That is also the reason that in many papers they only plot the k>0 side, right?

Comment: What sort of excitations? What do you mean a step potential - if you add a non-translationally invariant potential to the system then momentum will stop being a good quantum number.

Comment: Bogoliubov excitations or in general the momentum distribution of particles n_k

Comment: I mean, how are you creating the excitation? This may be true at finite temperature but it doesn't mean you can't create a state with an arbitrary momentum distribution, it will just be strongly non thermal.

Comment: @jacob1729; I assume zero temperature and see the Gross-pitaevskii equation

Comment: @jacob1729; I refer to n_k = fft(n(x))

Comment: @jacob1729; So, n_k = n_(-k) or not?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this isn't even really special to BEC's in particular.  This is really about what the Fourier transform of a single-particle wave function looks like.

Comment: @SuperCiocia could maybe answer this question

Comment: @march: I found it!

Comment: @jacob1729: should I now delete the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the real space spectrum $n(x)$ is real, $n(-k)$ will be equal to $n(k)$ complex conjugated.